# Handle custom domain in website builder?

Tags: server, dns, subdomain

I'm trying to build a website builder (that will generate static websites at the beginning).

I don't know how to handle the situation when I need to allow customers to use their own domain.

I did a brainstorm and here is my thought:

1. Generate their static website (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) into a folder on my
   server
2. When customer enters the domain in my website builder tool => Tell
   them to point the domain to my server IP address
3. Then write a command to automatically generate virtual host/server
   block for each of those domains, and point to the location of static
   files (HTML, CSS, JavaScript)

I think that kind of approach is quite incorrect somehow.

Can you please tell me what is the approach that website builders like Shopify did this?